# Netlogo documentation: variables list

Tags: netlogo

this might sound like a dumb question but, does anyone know how can I get a list of the variables (including auxiliary and dummies) from my Netlogo code?

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Reflexion extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/Reflection-Extension) might be what you're looking for.

As per the documentation:

> `reflection:globals` reports a list with the names of all global variables breeds

and:

> `reflection:breeds` reports a list of all breed names, and all their variables, default variables included.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, I went ahead and dowloaded it but it is giving me an error (see below) .  I am using the latest Netlogo version 6.0.1 <br>  NetLogo is unable to supply you with more details about this error.  Please report the problem 
 at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues, or to bugs@ccl.northwestern.edu, and paste the 
contents of this window into your report.

Comment: This extension is pretty new, and there might still be bugs in it. If you're getting that kind of runtime error, I would encourage to open an issue at https://github.com/NetLogo/Reflection-Extension/issues/new.